# Why would you choose GWT /Errai over React.js or Vue.js for building large applications?

Tags: java, reactjs, vue.js, gwt, errai

Given that a developer is tasked to build large applications, e.g Booking sites, Video Conferencing apps, etc)

As a seasoned React.js or Vue.js developer, what would be the compelling reasons that a seasoned Java developer should start learning to program with React or Vue?

As a seasoned Java developer (that may also have experience with GWT/Errai framework) what would be the main reasons to stick with developing such applications in Java/GWT/Errai framework instead of jumping into doing it in React or Vue Javascript frameworks?

What are the modern reasons [reactive, progressive, and micro-frontend style] that should be considered to choose whether to use a shiny Javascript framework like React/Vue and **scrape** the idea of building applications with such Java frameworks mentioned?

Comment: "reactive, progressive, and micro-frontend style" is also possible with GWT/j2cl

Comment: This is not a question for stackoverflow

Comment: @ElHoss can you elaborate, maybe in an answer?

Comment: Overall it depends on the requirements. And I think you cannot get a good answer here. Check the frameworks and check your development team and decide what suits best. It's  a bit like the question "What's better: chocolate or gummy bears?"